# Why does my menu keep disappearing?

Tags: android, menu

As soon as I build a new project I set up my menu with a search option with the following code.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);


        mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mSearchMenuItem);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

when I run it and test it seems to work alright but as soon as I add more files to the project the menu and the actionbar disappears forever? I am not changing the styles of my project and I want my actionbar/search option menu to stay there.

As soon as the app launches im launching a dialog which goes to a webview but in the back ground i want this search option and i want the user to be able to search when the dialog disappears.

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

your menu xml must be like this

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
```

***YourActivity.class***

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    //implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener before this method
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
            new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                    // Do something when collapsed
                    return true; // Return true to collapse action view
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                    // Do something when expanded
                    return true; // Return true to expand action view
                }
            });
}
```

if you write like this it would be easy (=